# Stream Data from iPhone to Wowza Server

Tags: iphone, avfoundation, rtmp, wowza

How can i live stream data fetched from AVAssets to Wowza Server?
Actually i am finding difficulty in creating RTMP Stream. Any Sample code/Link help will be appreciated.